# How to get average order data for days of week between two dates in mongodb aggregate?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to get all orders between two dates, group them by day of week, then average them. Currently the code looks like this:

```
export const getOrderValuesBetweenTwoDates = async (
  from: number,
  to: number,
) => {
  // from, and to are guaranteed to be Mondays, 00:00
  const orders = await OrderModel.find({
    createdAt: { $lt: to, $gte: from },
  }).exec();

  const totalOfDaysOfWeek = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];

  orders.forEach((order) => {
    const daysSinceFrom = (order.createdAt - from) / dayInMilliseconds;
    const dayOfWeek = Math.floor(daysSinceFrom) % 7;

    totalOfDaysOfWeek[dayOfWeek] =
      (totalOfDaysOfWeek[dayOfWeek] || 0) + order.value;
  });

  const numberOfWeeks = Math.floor((to - from) / dayInMilliseconds / 7);
  const averageOfDaysOfWeek = totalOfDaysOfWeek.map((v) =>
    Number((v / numberOfWeeks).toFixed(2)),
  );
  return averageOfDaysOfWeek;
};
```

However, this is not really performant, and I guess if it could be written in aggregation, it would be. Is that possible to convert the above into aggregation?

Sample input (2 weeks):

```
[
  // 1st mon (total 5)
  { createdAt: 345600000, value: 2 },
  { createdAt: 345600000, value: 3 },
  // 1st tue
  { createdAt: 432000000, value: 1 },
  // 1st wed
  { createdAt: 518400000, value: 1 },
  // 1st thu
  { createdAt: 604800000, value: 1 },
  // 1st fri
  { createdAt: 691200000, value: 1 },
  // 1st sat
  { createdAt: 777600000, value: 1 },
  // 1st sun (2 total)
  { createdAt: 864000000, value: 2 },
  // 2nd mon (1 total)
  { createdAt: 950400000, value: 1 },
  // 2nd tue
  { createdAt: 1036800000, value: 1 },
  // 2nd wed
  { createdAt: 1123200000, value: 1 },
  // 2nd thu
  { createdAt: 1209600000, value: 1 },
  // 2nd fri
  { createdAt: 1296000000, value: 1 },
  // 2nd sat
  { createdAt: 1382400000, value: 1 },
  // 2nd sun (4 total)
  { createdAt: 1468800000, value: 1 },
  { createdAt: 1468800000, value: 1 },
  { createdAt: 1468800000, value: 2 },
]
```

In the above example I've made 2 special cases, for Monday, and Sunday. There are multiple orders for those days.

For the first Monday there is an order with value 2, and 3, to 5 in total. For the second Monday there is only one order with value 1. The average should be 3.

For Sunday, the first one, there's an order with value 2, and for the second Sunday, there are 3 orders with total value of 4. I'm expecting the average to be 3.

I'm expecting the result to be `[3,1,1,1,1,1,3]`

Comment: please add sample input and expected output

Comment: your expected output is wrong since for `Monday` avg is `(2+3+1)/3 = 2` not `3` and also for `Sunday` is `(2+1+1+2)/4 = 1.5` not `3` : )

Comment: I get your point, please examine the function I wrote to understand the logic. I'm not looking for the average of all orders on a given day of week. I'm summing a given day's order total, and average only the different days.

Answer (score 1):

1. format the date using [$dateToString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/)
2. use `$sum` to get sum of same day of week
3. get day of week by [$dayOfWeek](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dayOfWeek/)
4. group by days of week and get average by [$avg](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/avg/)
5. project to get data as desired format

weekDay in output will be number between 1 (Sunday) and 7 (Saturday).

test it at [mongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5TaULXx3Fjp)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      createdAt: {
        "$dateToString": {
          "date": {
            "$toDate": "$createdAt"
          },
          "format": "%Y-%m-%d"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$createdAt",
      "value": {
        "$sum": "$value"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "createdAt": {
        $dayOfWeek: {
          "$toDate": "$_id"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$createdAt",
      "average": {
        "$avg": "$value"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      _id: 0,
      weekDay: "$_id",
      average: 1
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Sorry, my bad, gave an example input that weren't considering any edge cases. Please see my updated input. Unfortunately it doesn't work with that.

Comment: is your input data exactly like that or you pass real date as number? i convert 0 to date and it will be `1970-01-01` and it's `friday` that time so that's why you get wrong output  and also the returning array is from `Sunday` to `Saturday`

Comment: You're right... Will update the answer. Sorry about that. My above function was trusting the from is Monday, and didn't run any checks, I guess that's why. Will update the answer, but it doesn't work anyways as it gets average of all of them. However, with your much appreciated help I was able to work out something that solves the problem.

Comment: updated the answer @GergőHorváth

Comment: It works, but only if all the orders are made at 00:00. What I've found working is to group by day of week, year, and day of year, and sum the values. Then group by day of week, and average the sums. This way it doesn't matter at what time the order is made, but only the orders made at the same day will be summed. What do you think? If you agree that this would be an optimal solution, update your answer, and I'll accept it.

Comment: It has another downside of that if for a given day of week, for example Wednesday, there aren't any orders, that index will be skipped, and we're left with 6 indexes, not knowing which day of week is missing.